# Import SQL result to txt file in One single line

Tags: amazon-redshift, export-to-csv

I have a PostgreSQL query. Below the query.

```
select  concat('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyz',concat('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyz','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyz')) as ret3
union all 
select  concat('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyz',concat('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyz','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyz')) as ret3
union all
select  concat('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyz',concat('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyz','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyz')) as ret3
```

The result of the query when exported to txt file is below

[image: Screenshot of the output file]

But I need the data to be exported in Text file on single line. Sample format is below

[image: Required format of text file]

The requirement is, how can we export the data warehouse data to a text file , but in single line .

I tried a normal txt file import , PFB the screenshot ,

[image: screenshot]

but the result is 3 line. Can somebody help, is there any way we can export the data warehoue result to a tet file ith a single line output.

Comment: If you want one line, then write one SELECT with [a single concat](https://dbfiddle.uk/xNvvyJkO). Additionally: the nested concat is useless `concat('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyz','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyz','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyz')` will work just fine

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  The requirement is, How to get multiple-row data to a text file in a single column. Even if he concat, the data comes in a row basis. I have 55 lakh rows, but I need those to be exported to a text file in a single line as mentioned in 2nd screenshot.

Comment: The you should provide an example that reflects your actual question. The DBFiddle is the answer to the question you asked. Also: Postgres or Redshift? Despite what Amazon marketing is telling you those are two very different database products and a solution for Postgres might not work with Redshift.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Redshift is the dW. Is there any tool for exporting multiple rows to a single line in text file?